# How to Fire Mail Using mailgun Laravel From Localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5, mailgun

I am stuck to send mail using mailgun from localhost I am using

```
Route::get('send_test_email', function(){
    Mail::raw('Sending emails with Mailgun and Laravel is easy!', function($message)
    {
        $message->to('shahjad.ahmad89@gmail.com');
    });
});
```

and configure .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@test.demo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=test.demo.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-3d94c7e39983b*******74b9fd9
```

I am getting error

**Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/test.demo.com/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response: Forbidden**

How to fix it Please give me any suggestion to resolved this issue